# How do I specify in an ARM template that my storage account should have `Public network access` set to `Disabled`?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-storage-account

**How do I specify in an ARM template that my storage account should have `Public network access` set to `Disabled` ?**

I have the following `storageAccounts` resource in an ARM template and when I upload the template I was expecting to see `Public network access` set to `Disabled`, but instead I see `'Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP Addresses'`, I have tried to put a storage account to `Public network access=Disabled` manually and export that template and it has the same as I do, so not quite sure how to do it.

My understanding of it is that as long as I keep the virtual networks + IP Addresses to empty arrays then it's the same as putting `Public access` to `Disabled`, not sure if this is the logic.

**Public network access result of uploading the template:**

[image: Public network access result of uploading the template]

**The resource defined in my ARM template:**

```
{
"type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
"name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
"apiVersion": "2017-10-01",
"sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('storageAccountSku')]",
    "tier": "[parameters('storageAccountTier')]"
},
"kind": "StorageV2",
"location": "[parameters('storageAccountLocation')]",
"tags": {},
"identity": {
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
},
"properties": {
    "defaultToOAuthAuthentication": false,
    "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
    "AllowBlobPublicAccess": false,
    "targetResourceId": "",
    "networkAcls": {
        "resourceAccessRules": [],
        "bypass": "AzureServices",
        "defaultAction": "Deny",
        "ipRules": [],
        "virtualNetworkRules": []
    },
    "publicNetworkAccess": "Disabled",
    "accessTier": "Hot"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see that you are using `"apiVersion": "2017-10-01"` and it is a very old version of ARM template for storage account. To avoid the conflicts, use the latest version which is `"apiVersion": "2023-01-01"`.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2023-01-01/storageaccounts?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template) for all the latest available Api versions of`"Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"`.

*Complete code is given below.*

```bash
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageaccountname": {
            "defaultValue": "teststorejah",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "storageAccountType": {
            "defaultValue": "Standard_GRS",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Standard_LRS",
                "Standard_GRS",
                "Standard_ZRS",
                "Premium_LRS"
            ],
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Accounttype"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2023-01-01",
            "name": "[parameters('storageaccountname')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
            },
            "kind": "StorageV2",
            "properties": {
                "networkAcls": {
                    "defaultAction": "Deny",
                    "bypass": "AzureServices",
                    "ipRules": [],
                    "virtualNetworkRules": []
                },
                "publicNetworkAccess": "Disabled"
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help @Jahnavi it worked and I didn't actually understand before now that these API versions targeted the individual resource types and that not all of the resources have the same API versions available, i.e. that in this case the storage account might support "2023-01-01" while a vNet might not support that API version.